# server taking too much time to serve static files

Tags: python, django

In my django project, I am using django=1.8, ngix, uwsgi, postgresql

my project is deployed in a live server which os is ubuntu 16.04

when I am requesting the home page, then here is the scenario of the times taking to serve static files as mentioned below.
[image]

static files taking too much time to be served. But if I request individual static file from browser, then it takes a few milliseconds.

my site is very slow and the circle on browser tab is moving for long time to response.

Please help me, what can i do...

Comment: We can't help because you haven't given any information about how you are serving these files.

Comment: True... we don't know anything about the server setup. I would suggest you to serve static files through nginx (or whatever you are using to serve the project). Also check that the server is working fine (it doesnt need more resources).

Comment: We also don't know how you load those files on the client side. You claim that loading one by one is fast. But then you load in your app and it is slow. Do you load all those statics in parallel? Because I don't see any other way for that to happen. Anyway 9min for loading 24kb? There's something seriously wrong here.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for your reply. I am serving my files via nginx. nginx is working as proxy server. nginx serves any static request bypassing the server request. Also, I have a stitc root directory which has been created by the comman "python manage.py collectstatic".